# how to specify this selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a selector like this:

```
$('.user-box-container').hide();
```

now we are using this in another part and want to show the 'other' one so I was thinking I'd wrap it like so:

```
<div class='user-container-wrappers'>
<div class='user-box-container'>

</div>
</div>
```

How would I specify this? Tried this and googled but this is a bit beyond me:

```
$('.user-container-wrappers.user-box-container').hide();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('.user-container-wrappers .user-box-container').hide();
```

---

`$('.user-container-wrappers.user-box-container')` --> means element with class `user-container-wrappers` and `user-box-container`

---

You need

```
$('.user-container-wrappers .user-box-container')
                           ^ //space here
```

---

`$('.user-container-wrappers .user-box-container')` --> means element with class `.user-box-container` inside element with class `user-container-wrappers`